# Is this a correct definition for fundamental class of a subvariety?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, hodge-theory

Let $X$ be a projective, smooth variety over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $Y$ in $X$ be a possibly singular closed subvariety of dimension $k$.

Given $\omega \in H^k(X)$, we can restrict $\omega$ to the smooth locus of $Y$ and integrate. I *think* (but I am not sure) that this is always finite, and in particular defines a class of $H^k(X)^*$. Is this a correct definition of the fundamental class $[Y]$ of $Y$ (which could also be obtained by triangulating $Y$)?

Why is the integral $\int_{Y \setminus Y_{Sing}} \omega$ always finite? Is it?

A big machinery way to approach this would be to consider the resolution of singularities $\tilde{Y} \to Y \to X$, and pullback $\omega$ to $\tilde{Y}$ instead and integrate, knowing that the difference is essentailly a set of measure zero because $\tilde{Y} \to Y$ is a birational. But this is way overpowered!

(Really I am trying to prove that if $\phi : X \to X'$ is a regular map, then $[\phi^{-1}(Y)] = \phi^*[Y]$, thinking of the fundamental class as linving in cohomology after using universal coefficients. From the definition outlined above I think it is a consequence of Fubini's theorem, but I might be mistaken...)

I would appreciate a good reference!

Comment: Yes, this integral finite but could be zero or nonzero and different from 1. Thus, thus is a wrong way to define the fundamental class. A correct definition can be given by using a triangulation of Y or resolution of singularities.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thanks! Do you think you could tell me an example? What is the issue of it being different from one?

Comment: consider X which is the product of two projective lines and Y one of these lines. Now find $\omega$ which restricts to the trivial class on Y.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Doesn't the pullback of the trivial class along the projection suffice? I'm confused. By trivial class do you mean a generator of $H^2$ on $Y$?

Comment: @MoisheCohen Unless I am mistaken, the bottom of page 33 in Griffiths and Harris seems to suggest that this approach does work.

Comment: Their remark is that every (irreducible) subvariety always carries a fundamental class. This is absolutely correct and, as I said above, can be proven in two ways. However, you cannot take a randomly chosen degree $k$ cohomology class $\omega$ (where $k$ is the real dimension of $Y$) and hope that its pull-back to $Y$ defines the (dual of) the fundamental class of $Y$. However this *is* true for *some choice* of $\omega$.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Sorry, I am still trying to understand. On page 61, Griffiths and Harris define a functional on $H^{2k}_{Dr}$ by pulling back *any* form $\omega$ to V and integrating. Thus they determine a class a cohomology class in $H^{2n - 2k}$. I don't understand how this is not what I was suggesting above (only the integral over the smooth locus should matter?), and/or how this depends on the choice of the form. (I'm not trying to define the fundamental class in $H_*(Y)$, perhaps this is where there is  miscommunication?)

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I totally misread your question.

Comment: @MoisheCohen It's okay I appreciated the discussion. :)

Comment: @MoisheCohen I definitely could have been more precise , the text I was reading put the fundamental class of Y in X, not on Y. But I understand how that could have been confusing.

Comment: Yes; you are also loose with the coefficients: I assume you are working over the real numbers (since you are working with form and also sicne you are talking about dual - somehow I missed the $\star$ when I was reading the question). I will write down an answer in a day or so when I have time.